# The constructor Integer(int) is deprecated since version 9

Tags: java

I really want to change this old format in my code into a newer one as this one is deprecated,
if you could offer me something

```
new Integer(diagonal).toString();
```

Comment: Maybe if you remove the ".toString ()"-part of the question, you earn less downvotes. It's not really related to the otherwise legitimate question, even if it happens, that it only occurs in your code in such context.

Answer (score 4):

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#%3Cinit%3E(int)):

> It is rarely appropriate to use this constructor. The static factory [`valueOf(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)) is generally a better choice, as it is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance.

So do this:

```
public String toString() {
    return m.get(row) + Integer.valueOf(diagonal).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply convert the `Integer` to a string using the built-in method `toString()`:

```
return m.get(row) + Integer.toString(diagonal);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create an `Integer` object when what you want to do is convert an `int` to a `String`. The `Integer` class has a `static` method [`toString(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString-int-) for this purpose.

```java
return m.get(row) + Integer.toString(diagonal);
```